# pandas comparing column value with 0

Tags: pandas

I am having following dataframe

```
data = {'sc':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
    't1':['O','O','O','X','O','X','O','O'],
    'q1':[10,15,12,12,14,15,16,9],
    's1':[280,310,292,245,267,288,291,298],
    's2':[290,315,294,247,268,285,290,296],
    }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

   sc   t1  q1  s1  s2
0   a   O   10  280 290
1   a   O   15  310 315
2   a   O   12  292 294
3   a   X   12  245 247
4   b   O   14  267 268
5   b   X   15  288 285
6   b   O   16  291 290
7   b   O   9   298 296
```

I want to create a new column "s3" based on conditions

```
data['s3']=max(s1-s2,0) where t1="O" and
data['s3']=max(q1,14) where t1="X"
```

Can you pl help ?

Comment: What have you currently tried? If you have a specific programming issue, please provide a [reprex] so that we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make use of [**`np.where`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here:

```
import numpy as np

df['s3'] = np.where(
    df['t1'] == 'O',
    df['s1'].sub(df['s2']).clip(lower=0),
    df['q1'].clip(lower=14)
)
```

This then yields:

```
>>> df
  sc t1  q1   s1   s2  s3
0  a  O  10  280  290   0
1  a  O  15  310  315   0
2  a  O  12  292  294   0
3  a  X  12  245  247  14
4  b  O  14  267  268   0
5  b  X  15  288  285  15
6  b  O  16  291  290   1
7  b  O   9  298  296   2
```

If `s3` already exists, we can use `np.select` instead:

```
df['s3'] = np.select(
    [df['t1'] == 'O', df['t1'] == 'X'],
    [
       df['s1'].sub(df['s2']).clip(lower=0),
       df['q1'].clip(lower=14)
    ],
    default=df['s3']
)
```

Comment: I have a query. Suppose I am updating the column 's3' where values are already existing  and t1 column is having other values than 'O' and 'X' then my issue other values are getting replaced, can you suggest some simple way to do this ?

Comment: can I do something like df['t1']=="O" & df['sc']=="a" in np.select ?

Comment: basically i want to write first condition using "and" codition e.g. if df['sc']=="a" and df['t1']=="O" then .... else if df['t1']=="X" then ....

Comment: when I am doing in np.select I am getting following error cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: got an answer it requires additional () e.g. conditions = [
    (df['column_1'] > 5),
    (df['column_1'] <= 5) & (df['column_1'] > 0),
    (df['column_1'] == 0)]
choices = ['high','low','null']

df['column_2'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='null')
df